# PHP Service: Singleton or Static

Tags: php, design-patterns, service, static, singleton

I want to separate my data manipulation code from the controller by making a service.

I'm asking myself if it's better to do something like `Service::getInstance()->function()` (Singleton) or simply `Service::function()` (Static)

Normally, I will make a singleton service and people say that it's more testable.

But in my case, the service will use something like `Article::find($id)`.
So my question is: is it necessary to make a singleton if this singleton use static method? I think that in this case, the testability will change nothing. Is it right? I want to do it in the right way so I need your help.

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use an instance of an object? This way you can inject needed dependencies:

```
$articleObject = new Article($databaseForExample);
$article = $articleObject->find($id);
```

Comment: I am using a custom framework that really looks like Laravel. So finding an object is done like that but I just want to separate my validation code from the controller in the right way

Comment: Im not familiar with Laravel myself. In general you should use singletons for objects that you want to initialize once, like a database or cache service. For all other classes just create a new instance if you need functionality like that. There is no reason to use a static method for finding/getting a post.